# Using find command to get position and value of elements of a a matrix with a filter

Tags: matlab

I have a `[m,n]` matrix and I a want to find position of values which are not `0` and print them on screen. Using loop I do:

```
disp('4) go through C and print (i,j) where element is not 0');
[m,n] = size(C);
for i= 1:m
    for j= 1:n
        if(C(i,j) ~= 0)
            result = sprintf('Element at [%d,%d] is not 0, is %d', ...
            i, j, C(i,j));            
            disp(result);
        end
    end
end
```

And output is like this:

```
Element at [1,1] is not 0, is 1
Element at [1,2] is not 0, is 1
Element at [1,3] is not 0, is 1
Element at [1,4] is not 0, is 1
```

How can I do the exact same thing using the `find` command? I tried the code below but it produces 3 one dimensional arrays...how to relate and extract the output from them? or I am doing something wrong?

```
%Do the same thing with find
[i,j,k] = find(C ~= 0)
```

Comment: stop giving negative vots...will ya?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output arguments of the `find` function are organized as follows:

```
[Row of element, Column of element, Value of element]
```

Therefore, using this command:

```
[r,c,v] = find(C)
```

will yield 3 Nx1 arrays, each containing the above informations.

Therefore you could use the following code to achieve what you want, using the loop index to access each value in the arrays. Note that you can use [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to print formatted text instead of using both `sprintf` and `disp`.

```
[r,c,v] = find(C);

for k = 1:size(r,1)        
   fprintf('Element at [%d,%d] is not 0, it is %d\n',r(k),c(k),v(k)); 
end
```

With this input matrix:

```
C = [1 0 0 1;0 1 0 1;0 0 1 1]

C =

     1     0     0     1
     0     1     0     1
     0     0     1     1
```

we obtain the following output:

```
Element at [1,1] is not 0, is 1
Element at [2,2] is not 0, is 1
Element at [3,3] is not 0, is 1
Element at [1,4] is not 0, is 1
Element at [2,4] is not 0, is 1
Element at [3,4] is not 0, is 1
```

Comment: You beat me to it:) Do you think I should delete my answer?

Comment: haha yeah by a few seconds I see! Mhh I don't know if you should delete it...I really don't mind if you keep it posted :)

Comment: Thanks, I deleted it anyway. Your answer was both quicker and better.